# Product of polynomes in extensions

Tags: polynomials, extension-field

Sorry if this is an elementary question. Let $K$ be a field and $L$ an extension of $K$. Let $P,Q\in{K[X]}$, so that $Q$ divides $P$ in $L[X]$, i.e. so that there exists a polynome $R\in{L[X]}$ so that $P=QR$. Then $R\in{K[X]}$.

I think this is a consequence of the unique factorisation of $P$ as a product of irreducible polynomes of $K[X]$, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Polynomial rings over fields are euclidean, so we can use euclidean division.
There hence exists $A,B \in K[x]$ such that $P = AQ + B$ and $B$ has a smaller degree than $Q$.
This equation is still true over $L$. But over $L$, the polynomial $Q$ divides the polynomial $P$. Thus, we can conclude that $B = 0$ and $A = R$ by uniqueness of factorization. From that, we get that $R = A \in K[x]$ as desired.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Only one thing, since $P=RQ=AQ$ (a priori, in $L[X]$), can we just say that $R=A$ since $L[X]$ is an integral domain?

Answer (score 1):

The relation $P=QR$ gives a linear system for the coefficients of $R$.
This system has entries in $K$ because $P,Q \in K[x]$.
If this system has a solution in $L$, then this solution can be found using Gaussian elimination. Therefore, the solution is in $K$ because Gaussian elimination only uses rational operations on the entries and these operations never leave $K$, which is a field.